Are the codes messing eachother up? (batch file)
I have a set of code, with which I want to increase my volume and play a video
if (@a==@b) @end /*

:: batch portion

@ECHO OFF

cscript /e:jscript "%~f0"


:: JScript portion */

var shl = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    shl.SendKeys(String.fromCharCode(0xAF));
}

cd "mario\assets"
call "mario.mp4"

when I split the code into two files both work fine. The video is in a subfile. Is that what's messing it up? I tried creating a third batch file to run the splitted code and that works, but I was wondering if there was a more convenient way to do this

One thing is for sure; between cscript /e:jscript "%~f0" and :: JScript portion */, you need an exit /b or a goto :eof. Before whichever of those you choose, you need to move cd "mario\assets", and call "mario.mp4" there. And you need to remove call from the latter of those, possibly even replacing that with start "".

Here's a modified version of what you've got.
@if (@a==@b) @then

:: batch portion
@ECHO OFF
cscript /e:jscript "%~f0"
cd "mario\assets"
start mario.mp4
exit /b

@end

// JScript portion
var shl = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    shl.SendKeys(String.fromCharCode(0xAF));
}

Changes

The cd and call commands are not JScript, AFAIK. They belong in the batch portion.
The batch portion needs an exit /b so that it doesn't attempt to run (or even parse) the remainder of the file, which isn't batch syntax.
start is probably the way you want to "launch" the .MP4 file.

Batch/JScript Polyglot Ideas
Here are some other styles for this combining batch/cmd and JScript together in one file.

A Polyglot for jscript in batch
JScript and Batch Hybrid
js/vbs/html/hta and more hybrids and chimeras in cmd/bat

